# Immediate effect of extensive exercise on cognitive performance

Tags: exercise

What is the immediate effect of physical exercise on one's cognitive performance?

Most studies I have found a [study](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-athletes-way/201404/physical-activity-improves-cognitive-function) regarding the long term effect of a lifestyle which includes exercise and the outcome has been found to be positive and counteracted degeneration.

I have also found studies which examine the effect of short exercises (10-15 minutes, medium intensity) which has also found to have ["improved affective experience and enhanced cognitive processing"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3768113/)

What is the effect of a long workout (over 1h) on the mental capabilites?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Cognitive Sciences! Will you please provide the results of your initial research? For instance, after [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+you+learn+better+after+exercise&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS743US743&oq=learn+better+after&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.4879j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I found the [top entry](http://www.karenpostal.com/exercise-think-better/) to answer your question and provide some resources for further learning. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Not your question but related: in addition to research showing that you do learn better after exercise, [it also shows](https://www.livescience.com/55095-exercise-helps-you-retain-new-info.html) that you can retain more information by exercising a few hours after learning. This being said, individual effects also come into play (though they are beyond the scope of this forum).

Comment: One's "Mental capabilities" is quite broad/unclear. Could you perhaps try to specify it a bit more?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the two studies I found most informative. 
I am interested in the ability to learn, process information and perhaps problem solving abilities, such as logical problems, if that is not too broad.